# Firebase: Buscar un único hijo que contenga un dato concreto

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Leyendo la documentación de Firebase he visto que con orderByChild,  orderByKey,  y  orderByValue se pueden realizar consultas a la BD. (no se si lo he entendido bien)

Pero no llego a entender como puedo buscar un hijo concreto por un valor.
Es decir, si tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
Alumnos
     LwQHvEYFKbQ_gcGxiu5
              Nombre: Carlos
              Edad:   25
     LwQI011z0Nz0N8d5f2P
              Nombre: Luis
              Edad:   30
```

¿Como puedo realizar una consulta para obtener únicamente el nodo **Luis**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he solucionado de la siguiente forma:

```
BDreferencia.orderByChild("Nombre").equalTo("Luis").addListenerForSingleValueEvent.....
```